# Find a groupwise maximum and print the relevant row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, groupwise-maximum

I have a dataframe like this:

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5   MAX   ROW
 2   5  -8  19  -20   V5    R1
12   3   5   6   -9   V1    R2
 5   7   8  -1   19   V5    R3
 3  -2  -5   2    4   V3    R4
 6   1  -1  15    9   V4    R5
-3  -4   7   2    8   V5    R6
-6  -9   3   6    2   V2    R7
18  11  -3  13    2   V1    R8
-3  -4   7   2    8   V2    R9
-2  -3   4   7    4   V4    R10
-7  -5  27   3    1   V3    R11
```

V1-V5 are data columns, MAX shows the column name of the highest absolute value in each row and ROW is just a row counter.

I want to find absolute maximum value of each column grouped by MAX, given out by the ROW number.

For example:

The Maxima in V1 are in row R2 and R8, so I compare the V1 column of the 2 rows R2 and R8. Its 12 and 18, so R8 would be the result I want to get.

V2 is in row R7 and R9, so I compare the V2 column of R7 and R9. Its -9 and -4 so the result would be R7 for -9 (signs don`t matter).

So far I just subset the data according to MAX, so I got 5 individual dataframes and then i sorted the relevant column manually. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify how you want the output structured but here is an idea with `tidyverse` where we melt the data frame and filter, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
 gather(var, val, - c(6, 7)) %>%
 filter(MAX == var) %>%
 group_by(MAX) %>%
 slice(which.max(abs(val))) %>%
 select(-var)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 3
> # Groups:   MAX [5]
>   MAX   ROW     val
>   <fct> <fct> <int>
> 1 V1    R8       18
> 2 V2    R7       -9
> 3 V3    R11      27
> 4 V4    R5       15
> 5 V5    R1      -20
> ```

Comment: Thank you! The structure of the output is not really relevant, all I need is the row number in any form. Your idea looks very promising, I will try it right now, thank you!

Comment: This is working, but it gives me the wrong rows for negative values. I need the highest absolute values...so -9 for example is more than 5.

Comment: Just wrap val in `abs()`

Comment: I tried that already, but this somehow gives me not every single result. It gives me only the rows with positive values.

Comment: Ok, have a look now

Answer (score 2):

A different `dpylr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(MAX) %>%
 mutate(res = max(abs(eval(as.symbol(MAX))))) %>%
 filter(res == abs(eval(as.symbol(MAX))))

     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5 MAX   ROW     res
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int>
1     2     5    -8    19   -20 V5    R1       20
2     6     1    -1    15     9 V4    R5       15
3    -6    -9     3     6     2 V2    R7        9
4    18    11    -3    13     2 V1    R8       18
5    -7    -5    27     3     1 V3    R11      27
```

Here it, first, groups by "MAX", evaluates "MAX" as symbol and returns the maximum absolute value. Then, it keeps the rows with the maximum absolute value.